# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, импорт

Операционная система Linux/Ubuntu 18.04 
И такая ошибка с каждой библиотекой. Как можно решить? Устанавливаю через pip install requests. Версии python: python --version
Python 2.7.15+

python3 --version
Python 3.7.4

Comment: Как устанавливали? `pip2 install requests` и `pip3 install requests`?

Comment: `pip` устанавливает модули в python2.7, который есть на Ubuntu по-умолчанию. Чтобы установить библиотеку на python3, нужно использовать команду `pip3 install module_name`. Но, скорее всего, ваша проблема даже не в том. На 18.04 установлен python 3.6 и тут сначала надо понять как вы устанавливали python3.7

Comment: Если вы сделали так, что командой python3 у вас вызывается python3.7 - у меня плохие новости. Недавно мне пришлось из-за этого переустанавливать систему) Мораль басни такая - никогда не надо трогать версии python, установленые по-умолчанию. Если вам нужен python 3.7, то поставьте его так, чтобы он вызывался командой python3.7, потом создавайте на его основе виртуальное оркужение и там уже ставьте любые модули.

Comment: Я себе даже в док скопировал инструкцию из какой-то статьи, как ставить python 3.8, чтобы все работало.  С 3.7 скорее всего похожая история. Делюсь: https://docs.google.com/document/d/18JLSZIBLIkSgQlJ8JN7s8DaYdFKcH1kXT65ABklK7r8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Питон 2 — `python`,`pip` , питон 3 —`python3`,`pip3`.Если что можно добавить alias'ами