# Установил модуль "keyboard", а python его не видит

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я установил модуль "keyboard", а Python его не видит.

Импортировал модуль я так:

```
from keyboard import is_pressed, write, send
```

Но как бы я не старался переустанавливать модуль стандартный IDLE его не видит, как это можно исправить?

Проблема скорее всего появилась когда я устанавливал новую версию Python

Мои попытки установки и переустановки:

[image: Стандартный IDLE]
[image: Удаление модуля и последующая его переустановка.]

Дополнение:

Только-что попробовал запустить Python файл через cmd и каким-то чудом он не стал жаловаться на отсутствие библиотеки и просто заработал. Всё-таки я хочу разобраться почему так происходит. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: У Вас стоит две разных версии python? Попробуйте просто запустить python из cmd (просто интерпретатор, не передавая ему файл скрипта), какую версию напишет?

Comment: Посмотрите данный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044052/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests). Возможно `pip` установил пакет на `python2`. Как написано в предыдущем комментарии. проверьте вашу версию `python`. Пропробуйте `pip3 install keyboard` для установки на `python3`

Comment: @V-Mor Версия Python у меня Python 3.9.1 (https://i.imgur.com/kiBbUsn.png)
@Sherlock У меня никогда небыл установлен любой Python 2.x, установка 100% была сделана на Python 3.9.1, так же я уже пробовал ранее устанавливать библиотеку при помощи команды `pip3`

Comment: Возможно, глупый вопрос, но Вы перезапускали IDLE после установки модуля? А то мало ли...

Comment: @V-Mor Да, я перезагружал IDLE, действительно странный вопрос) Я так-же неоднократно перезагружал полностью систему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 вариант решения:** Чтобы Python увидел библиотеку запускать скрипт нужно через командную строку (cmd).
Не знаю как так происходило, но оно так работало...

**2 вариант решения:** Так-же работает вариант переустановить систему и последующая установка чистейшего Python на новую систему, тогда внутри системы Python перестанет конфликтовать сам с собой или с системой. Незнаю как так получилось, но это скорее всего конфликт Python с чем-то что мне не ведомо)

Мне помогло лишь переустановить полностью систему, тем самым конфликты системы с Python видимо исчезли и он стал нормально воспринимать установленную мной библиотеку "keyboard"
[Ранее я уже пробовал переустанавливать Python или откатываться назад на предыдущие версии (может там что-то бы заработало), но нечего не помогало, лишь переустановка системы **(Что достаточно радикально!)**, помогло мне справиться с проблемой.]

*Это одиночная ошибка которую я допустил я сам и из-за этого скорее всего подобных случаев не будет происходить с другими людьми, было неправильно задавать такой вопрос здесь)*